# Use workflow Business logic layer

Tags: c#, mvvm, visual-studio-2012, workflow, business-logic

I use visual studio 2012 and want to use the `MVVM` design pattern in my application.

I'm looking for documents, books and samples to help me to use workflow in the business logic layer of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what ui technology your using. We've used caliburn micro for several silver light apps with great success.

http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/